# How can my asp.net web app when page event caused by user back button or refresh button?

Tags: asp.net, http, browser

How can my app determine which of these caused a page event:

1. User pressed browser back button
2. User refreshed browser page

Comment: There's heaps of ways to do this... webforms controls are posted, browser events can be intercepted via javascript and then passed to the server, guids can be attached to email links for tracking, etc... I don't think anyone on here is going to post solutions with code examples though. You'll need to narrow down the question scope

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find whether the user clicks browser back button or Refresh button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292204/how-to-find-whether-the-user-clicks-browser-back-button-or-refresh-button)

Answer (score 0):

To handle this problem, you need to validate when the user had been press the back button, on Page_Load event:

For example:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    Response.Write("Page Loaded");
}
else
{
    Response.Write("Page Reloaded");
}
```